# Using jQuery to get the content of div.class to replace content of title tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I need to work around a limitation on my company's platform where pages can only be rendered with the filename as the title. I don't want to change my file-names to have values like, "This page title with spaces, and maybe illegal characters", because I don't want my URLs to have a bunch `%20`'s and illegal characters in them, so I've been trying to figure out how to use the contents of another section of the page over which I do have control - the breadcrumb - as the "title".

I've been trying to use jQuery's `.get` and `.replaceWith` to replace the contents of the `title` tag with the contents of `span.ms-pagetitle`, which contains the part I can edit, but I'm a jQuery noob, and just haven't been able to suss it out.

Comment: place your code here that can be helpful to us that what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
$('title').text($('span.ms-pagetitle').text())
```

This should be run only once; usually inside a `$(document).ready()` function. The `.ms-pagetitle` element ought to have no children.

Two things are going on here:

`$('span.ms-pagetitle').text()` first selects any items matching `span.ms-pagetitle`. Hopefully there is just one, but it will grab them all. Use `:first` or another more specific selector to get the one you want. `.text()` will

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the
>   matched elements.

...hence the idea to keep the span childless.

So that will result in a string of text.

`$('title').text('string')` will *set* the contents of a selected tag when passed a string (and *get* when used with no argument), so you are setting the selected title text as the contents of the `<title>` tag here.

Comment: This worked perfectly, @ Alex. And many thanks for including a description of what was taking place; that is incredibly helpful to my understanding! Now if I can only get around IE being the supported browser, and the default setting for intranet sites being Compatibility mode... Breaks this solution |-(